# r stacked bar total value

Tags: r, plot, stacked

I want to create a plot (EDA) about data that is collected from houses (devices in houses). But I'm stuck..

The data is looking like this:

```
df$device    df$date       df$time    df$value
boiler       2015-01-13    12:15      0.0009
boiler       2015-01-13    12:30      0.0007
boiler       2015-01-13    12:45      0.0005
boiler       2015-01-13    13:00      0.0010
TV           2015-01-13    12:15      0.0009
TV           2015-01-13    12:30      0.0007
TV           2015-01-13    12:45      0.0005
TV           2015-01-13    13:00      0.0010
boiler       2015-01-14    12:15      0.0009
boiler       2015-01-14    12:30      0.0007
boiler       2015-01-14    12:45      0.0005
boiler       2015-01-14    13:00      0.0010
TV           2015-01-14    12:15      0.0009
TV           2015-01-14    12:30      0.0007
TV           2015-01-14    12:45      0.0005
TV           2015-01-14    13:00      0.0010
```

The data is measured over 8 months (Jan till September). I want to make a plot, with:
    Y- axis = measured value 
    X- axis = months 
    Plots = all the devices

I tried, with:

```
df$monthnumber <- month(df$Date)
test <- table(df$Device, df$monthnumber)

barplot(counts1,col=rainbow(7), xlim = c(1,15),
        legend = c(rownames(counts1)), bty = "L")
```

What lead to the next image:

Result: [image]
But, that is wrong. Because it contains how often an device is measured. I do not know how I can add the TOTAL VALUE per month for each application (a summation).

I tried:

```
test$value <- aggregate (df$Measurevalue, by = list(genergy$Device), sum)
```

But an error was given:

> Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "value", value = list(Group.1 = c("Boiler",       :
>     replacement has 7 rows, data has 285896

How can I tackle this problem? 
- A stacked bar, with the TOTAL VALUE of each device, with (`y= energy`), (`X= months`)

Comment: Have you tried plotting using ggplot?

Comment: Yes, but the main problem was to get the summation of the value. It didn't work in my case, because (i guess) the dataframes differs from lengt. But i really have no idea how i could fix that.

Comment: So:
- with month nummers (x) 
- with measured value (y)
- with total value (in the bar)

And i do not understand how i can add (to my table) an extra variable with the measured value per device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you could use a combination of `dplyr` and `ggplot`

```
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")

df <- data.frame(device = c("boiler","boiler","boiler","boiler","TV","TV","TV","TV","boiler","boiler","boiler","boiler","TV","TV","TV","TV"), 
                     date = c("2015-01-13","2015-01-13","2015-01-13","2015-01-13","2015-01-13","2015-01-13","2015-01-13","2015-01-13","2015-01-14","2015-01-14","2015-01-14","2015-01-14","2015-01-14","2015-01-14","2015-01-14","2015-01-14"),
                     time = c("12:15","12:30","12:45","13:00","12:15","12:30","12:45","13:00","12:15","12:30","12:45","13:00","12:15","12:30","12:45","13:00"),
                     value = c(0.009,0.007,0.005,0.001,0.009,0.007,0.005,0.001,0.009,0.007,0.005,0.001,0.009,0.007,0.005,0.001)
                     )
    df <- mutate(df,device = as.factor(device),
                 date = as.Date.character(date,format = "%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
      group_by(device) %>%
        mutate(sum(value))
```

The result is a summary by device on a daily basis
[image]

as you mentioned in your comment, you were looking to do it for a monthly basis - group the table based on the month

```
df<- group_by(df,m=as.factor(month(date)),device) %>%
summarise(s = sum(value))
ggplot(df,aes(x=m,y=s,fill=device)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

As, I don't have enough monthly data, the graph looks as follows..
[image]

**update: 27/06/2016**
following the input of the data, you run the following command. And then try summarising the data based on the month.

```
    df <- mutate(df,device = as.factor(device),
                  date = as.POSIXct((strftime(date,format = "%Y-%m-%d")))) %>%
         group_by(device)
```

Comment: Thank you, but my data contains almost 800,000 rows. So after e.g. device = c("boiler"....) is it possible to do this automatically?

Comment: Really thanks! But when im run your second code:

df<- group_by(df,m=as.factor(month(date)),device) %>%
summarise(s = sum(value))
ggplot(df,aes(x=m,y=s,fill=device)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")

I got this error: 
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”

Comment: class(df$Date)  --> "Date"

Comment: Thanks, i have the feeling that i'm almost there, but a new error is showed up:

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'm' not found

While, the first time I run the code block: 

    plotje <- group_by(plotje, m= as.factor(month(date)),device) %>%
      summarise(s = sum(value))

It gives no error (till I want to run the ggplot). So i cannot understand why m is not fount. (because i assign m to as.factor(month(date))

Comment: ggplot(plotje,aes(x= m,y= s,fill=device)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")

Comment: Hi Arun, no M doesn't exist. I also installed both packages.. but i guess that the bug is in:

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”

The first time I run the code, no error is given, till the ggplot line. After that, while I run the code again, I get an error (about to convert x to class posixit)

Comment: Thank you so much @Arun. Your solution works, I made an extra column df$month <- month(df$date) 

And then i applied your function. Thanks a lot